# Output types for Tekton Task

Tags: kubernetes, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I can't find some sort of list that would show accepted types for outputs in Tekton Tasks.
Is it somehow fixed or is it possible to use any file extension? I have been having troubles with .xml files in my case.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the tekton's output do not care what the file extension, all files output belong to `type: storage`.
validate types of outputs should be:

```
    // PipelineResourceTypeGit indicates that this source is a GitHub repo.
    PipelineResourceTypeGit PipelineResourceType = "git"

    // PipelineResourceTypeStorage indicates that this source is a storage blob resource.
    PipelineResourceTypeStorage PipelineResourceType = "storage"

    // PipelineResourceTypeImage indicates that this source is a docker Image.
    PipelineResourceTypeImage PipelineResourceType = "image"

    // PipelineResourceTypeCluster indicates that this source is a k8s cluster Image.
    PipelineResourceTypeCluster PipelineResourceType = "cluster"

    // PipelineResourceTypePullRequest indicates that this source is a SCM Pull Request.
    PipelineResourceTypePullRequest PipelineResourceType = "pullRequest"

    // PipelineResourceTypeCloudEvent indicates that this source is a cloud event URI
    PipelineResourceTypeCloudEvent PipelineResourceType = "cloudEvent"

    // PipelineResourceTypeGCS is the subtype for the GCSResources, which is backed by a GCS blob/directory.
    PipelineResourceTypeGCS PipelineResourceType = "gcs"
```